cannot find symbol import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
I'm following a tutorial online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze-SqcKi3q4) to add an app as pre-build app in Android Automotive. i run my program on Android stido it works but after i copy the necessary files in the Android Automotive and i launch the build. i get this error:
packages/apps/Car/myapplicationjava/src/com/example/myapplicationjava/MainActivi ty.java:5: error: cannot find symbol import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge; ^ symbol:   class EdgeToEdge location: package androidx.activity *
packages/apps/Car/myapplicationjava/src/com/example/myapplicationjava/MainActivi ty.java:16: error: cannot find symbol EdgeToEdge.enable(this); ^ symbol:   variable EdgeToEdge location: class MainActivity 2 errors
my code is :
MainActivity.java
package com.example.myapplicationjava;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }
}

now i want a solution for this problem
